# Can't get proper results with mechanize when using br.submit()

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to submit a form, and get the results of the page that it heads to after submitting the form. I'm using mechanize.

1) When I'm using the code to click on the first-button, it is getting a response. But when I read the response, it is showing the source of the same page (the page where the form is located). Not of the page that the browser is redirected to after the submission of the form.

```
    from mechanize import Browser
    br = Browser()
    br.open("http://link.net/form_page.php")
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form['number'] = '0123456789'
    response = br.submit(nr=0) 
    print response.read()
```

Now, when I do this, the source of the same page (i.e. form_page.php) is showing up. But, it should have shown the source of "results.php" (that is where the browser leads to when I do it manually)

2) There are multiple submit buttons in the page. I am clicking only the first one. But when I'm trying to click other submit buttons using nr=1 or nr=2, it is showing this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize  /_mechanize.py", line 524, in select_form
    raise FormNotFoundError("no form matching "+description)
    mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 1
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: You are selecting form with nr=0. why traceback error returned nr 1? what have you done with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you are selecting right form or make sure there is a form that you are selecting on the web page. you can check it by like this code :

```
for form in br.forms():
    print form
```

and see what result returned to you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642462/mechanize-br-submit-limitations) issue, where submit was calling some Javascript to validate the inputs before redirecting. It may be worth having a look at the HTML of the page and checking what it does on submit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://link.net/form_page.php")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['number'] = '0123456789'             ### try instead of 'br.form[]'
response = br.submit()                  ### no need to specify form again
text = response.read()
```

Don't forget about 'br.set_handle_robots(False)', 'br.set_all_readonly(False)', etc...